# PayPal Do capture API in Sailsjs

Tags: node.js, api, paypal, sails.js

i need to create a PayPal API for do capture in sails js, I've done R&D on google about it but i am not able to find out any solution of it.

i don't have created any PayPal API in my Carrier so i don't have any idea how to Create a API for PayPAl,

i've also tried to find any module for this in npmjs but i am not able to find one for this except paypal-ec, but i am not able to understand it's sample project on git, because that's is written in express and i don't have any idea about the express framework  objects, its stricture or any thing so i am stucked no where but in this API.

Please guide me how can i create a PayPal API for do capture in sailsjs with some simple technique or method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is the DoCapture of the PayPal API you could just use the [node-curl](https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-curl) module and make requests to the PayPal Classic API using cURL as shown in these [docs](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoCapture_API_Operation_NVP/).

Otherwise there are SDKs for the PayPal REST API [rest-api-sdk-nodejs](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-nodejs) you could use as well but you would have to familiarize yourself with how the [REST API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/) handles the capturing of payments.